# how to extend chai-as-promised with own assertions (properties and methods)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm using [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) + [chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) runner.
By simple Chai, the extension with own assertions works like this:
http://chaijs.com/api/plugins/#addProperty-section

How should it look by using chai-as-promised?